# Can't use keyboard & mouse after switch additional driver (xserver-xorg-...) on login account

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xorg, mouse, additional-drivers

I need some help about my Ubuntu 18.04 (installed in Dualboot).

I was going to work, but recently I changed my GTX 970 => RTX 3070. Once logged into Ubuntu I have a resolution stuck at 1024 * 768, which is not great for working. I told myself that it came from the dualboot which sometimes explodes resolution, loss of a screen (because I am in dualscreen) or loss of time. To my surprise, the second screen is not recognized and I have no other resolution option other than the one I have 1024 * 768.

I tell myself that there is a problem with the driver on the Nvidia side. Since the installation, I had never taken care of it (dualboot installed around 2 years ago).

I tried to rummage on internet and went to "Softwares & Updates" and "Additionnals Pilots" to check if there was not an Update Driver or other to do as we can see on the following screen :

[Additionals Drivers list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mulF.png)

I decided to take the one from NVIDIA with the owner setting & tested. The second NVIDIA option was not "proprietary & tested". I then applied the changes, waited, and restarted my PC.

And the problems started, nothing compared to the video, etc, ... The problem and that I have the impression by installing this driver that I lost the use of my keyboard and my mouse, which seems completely incomprehensible. I saw on the internet that the option which was checked as on the screen with "xserver-xorg -..." allows to control keyboard and mouse.

I have the possibility in the grub to use my keyboard, but as soon as I get to the ubuntu login account or simply by going into recovery mode, I cannot enter any input with my keyboard and the mouse being blocked too. Is it possible in the grub to edit the start-up commands to put the correct driver back or switch to recovery mode without having this controller pb?

Does anyone have an idea for successfully logging into a terminal, for example, but even then I'm not sure I can enter the login information. Is my diagnosis good? I would like to avoid reinstalling my Ubuntu, I have data to recover. Ubuntu recovery mode doesn't allow me to re-use keyboard & mouse.

If you need any additional information, please do not hesitate, I will try to come and answer you as soon as possible.

P.S: I finally re-switch my 3070 by my 970 in my PC. But, something has been changed on my ubuntu.
P.S2: When I try a live session with an USB Boot, there is no problem, keyboard & mouse works.
P.S3: I need to keep my OS and don't reinstall anything, because I need my work and files on it.

**REAL PROBLEM** => Can't use keyboard & mouse since login account. Resolution & dualscreen are now a little problem.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Cordially.

Comment: (1) Much newer releases are recommended for such hardware, the current 21.04 would be a good start. (2) Always install in UEFI mode with Secure Boot OFF. (3) Make sure to select the option to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, etc. to have the Nvidia drivers automatically installed.

Comment: Before resolving my Nvidia Drivers, I need to use my keyboard and mouse. Do you have any idea how to? Btw, I need to keep safe my works and files on my current ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The idea was commented above. Try booting a Ubuntu 21.04 live session. Does keyboard and mouse work there? There's your answer. You can do backups there also if you have no backups already (you should)

Comment: I wrote it in P.S2, yes if I use a USB boot and try a live session, my keyboard and mouse works well. Yes, I know.